# Apply a special effect to a scene area

Tags: unity, shaders, graphics-programming

My 2D game has a second camera on the scene that renders an upside down image of the scene and distorts it, giving the effect of water reflection. I render this camera first, and on top of it I render the main camera.

This is working correctly as expected, however, I want to improve it's performance by performing this process in small sections of the scene instead of the whole screen. I created a trigger to detect which items should be turned upside down and rendered.

How can I turn these items and distort them as I did with the whole scene, but only to the `GameObject`s detected inside the trigger?

Note: I can't assign them to a layer since the layer is already in use.

Comment: Have you explored using a [GrabPass](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-GrabPass.html) so that you only need to render the scene once?

Comment: Just use a GrabPass and assign it a name so it only gets rendered once

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a water effect like the one used in the *"Ramboat"* game, you need to that use a replica for each image of which you want water reflection and distortion, and then use a raw image in your second camera, with a minimum opacity value.

This gives you an effect, like as follows:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Inside the trigger : then activate object renderer.
Outside the trigger : then deactivate object renderer.

Comment: But that will affect my main camera too. Right?

Comment: right. And.. render the "water" camera to "Target texture". And place the texture on water areas ? (getting lost the trigger management?)